# $in across multiple columns in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with the following data

```
_id name    type
1   Banana  Fruit
2   Tomato  Vegetable
3   Carrot  Vegetable
4   Tomato  Fruit
```

My query input is an array of pairs

```
[
 {
  name : 'Banana',
  type : 'Fruit'
 },
 {
  name : 'Tomato',
  type : 'Vegetable'
 }
]
```

The result I want is the documents that match any of the pairs in the array

```
_id name    type
1   Banana  Fruit
2   Tomato  Vegetable
```

I tried

```
db.data.find({$and: [
    {name : {$in : ['Banana', 'Tomato']}},
    {type : {$in : ['Fruit', 'Vegetable']}}
]})
```

but I get

```
_id name    type
1   Banana  Fruit
2   Tomato  Vegetable
4   Tomato  Fruit
```

which is not what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        $or:[ 
            {
              name : 'Banana',
              type : 'Fruit'
            },
            {
              name : 'Tomato',
              type : 'Vegetable'
            }
        ]
    }
).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Banana", "type" : "Fruit" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Tomato", "type" : "Vegetable" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Carrot", "type" : "Vegetable" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Tomato", "type" : "Fruit" }
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Banana", "type" : "Fruit" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Tomato", "type" : "Vegetable" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query operator with the pairs

```
const array = [
  {
    "name": "Banana",
    "type": "Fruit"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tomato",
    "type": "Vegetable"
  }
]

db.data.find({ $or: array })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong, what you tried is expression where name is either "Tomato" or "Banana" and type is either "Vegetable" or "Fruit" but you want either "name is Tomato + type is Vegetable" or "name is Banana + type is Fruit"

instead, try

```
db.data.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          name: "Banana"
        },
        {
          type: "Fruit"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          name: "Tomato"
        },
        {
          type: "Vegetable"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```